# Global mongoose models

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to design the backend of a large application with many servers. There should be only one database (mongodb) and all of the servers should connect to it. I also want to design the backend in a way such that all servers can query anything  in the database. For example consider the `User` model. If I have a payment service, it will need to find information about the user, and so will the authentication service and so on.To do this in mongo (or mongoose in my case) is to have all my models somewhere all the servers can see.

A possible solution I thought of is to public all of my models on npm and then I can require them in each server but that doesn't seem like a very good solution. What are other alternatives I could do that follow best practices?

Comment: Solutions are totally based on the architecture you choose, if you want to apply Microservice, you can set up the data model as one service.   
If you want to set up a monorepo, you can use lerna or yarn workspace to manage the project and set the data model as a package.   
Even with your solution, you don't need to make your model public on npm, npm can install private git repo as well.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this in my opinion would be to put them in a private npm repo or refer to your private git repository.

Putting them in public space is, imo, asking for trouble and also pollutes npm somewhat as it's supposed to be livraywith wide usage possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a bad idea for you to be sharing domain logic and coupling your services at the database level, but, if you have strong conviction to going that route you can just store the code in a mono repo and just bootstrap the domain model within multiple application entry points.

If you want to package them up as independent modules for private npm, you can look into using lerna for package management.